# PHP ldap_error reports nothing

Tags: php

I am running the following and my command is failing.  It correctly stops at die() but does not print the ldap_error().

```
// Now for LDAP
          require_once('ldapconnect.php');

          $entry["mysqldbname"] = $value;
          $result = ldap_mod_del($ldapconn, $binddn, $entry)or die(ldap_error());
```

I already know the connection is fine as I have tested it here before and it's also working just fine on another page.  Any idea why my error isn't printing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the connection so it knows where to look.

Changed from:

```
$result = ldap_mod_del($ldapconn, $binddn, $entry)or die(ldap_error());
```

to:

```
$result = ldap_mod_del($ldapconn, $binddn, $entry)or die(ldap_error($ldapconn));
```

And now I'm getting the error I needed for troubleshooting.